# Suma de resultado

Tags: java

estoy comenzando recién con java, soy de nivel muy básico y como ejercicio estoy aumentando de 3 en 3 por medio de while hasta poner un limite de 125, todos esos valores que me da de 3 en 3 ¿Cómo puedo sumarlos entre si?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, revisa [help] y [ask]. En concreto, indica qué has intentado (con el código) y qué errores te has encontrado. Tienes un botón para editar la pregunta y añadir la información.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puede que te refieras a esto:

```
public class pregunta {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int sumaNumeros = 0;
    while (x < 125) {
        x += 3;
        sumaNumeros += x;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, y una disculpa, quizá me explique mal. En mi ejercicio ya tengo el resultado de 3 en 3 hasta 125, pero, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para sumar todos esos números entre si? Es decir, sumar todos esos resultados de 3, 6, 9 etc a partir de por ejemplo el código que me proporcionaste.

Comment: Ahi te dejo la posible respuesta que buscas, la variable que suma 3,6,9... la llame sumaNumeros, y un placer contestarte

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!!! tene en cuenta que te votaron negativo, tal vez porque contestaste una pregunta que era un ejercicio sin demostrar ningun intento y que para colmo termino cerrada. por favor, mira el [tour] y tambien [answer].. no todas las preguntas deben ser contestadas...